# how to add user groups choice field in symfony 2 fosuserbundle registration form?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have configured fosuserbundle in symfony 2, I am able to list/show details/add/edit/delete user groups?

I searched but could not find any help for adding user groups choice field in user registration form.

Comment: Same here. Did you find something ?

Answer (score 0):

have your read [how to override registration form](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) ?

your could add a custom group field in your custom registration form. 
Beware if you use 'fos_user.group_manager.default' service to provide select options, you may not want to provide all fosuser groups in your registration form

You can listen to "FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS" event to assign the group after form is submitted and valid (User infos are not saved yet)

Hope this helped